# d’Alembert Lagrangian for second rank tensors

Tags: field-theory, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation, index-notation

> Consider the Lorentz scalar Lagrange density
>   $$\mathcal{L}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu T^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta}$$
>   for a second rank tensor whose contravariant and covariant components are $T^{\alpha\beta}$, $T_{\alpha\beta}$ respectively. By varying with respect to each component $T^{\alpha\beta}$ separately, show that the set of generalized Euler-Lagrange equations for $\mathcal{L}$ give the set of equations of motion
>   $$\square^2T^{\alpha\beta}=0, \quad \text{for } \alpha,\beta=0,1,2,3.$$

In the previous statement, we have that $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor defined as 
$$\eta^{\mu\nu}\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
1 &\text{if}& \nu=\mu=0, \\
-1 &\text{if}& \nu=\mu=1,2,3, \\
1 &\text{if}& \nu\neq\mu, \\
\end{array}
\right. $$
and $\partial_\mu$ is the $4-$gradient given by 
$$\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu}.$$

Firstly, we can express the Lagrange density as 
$$\mathcal{L}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu T^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta^{\alpha\rho}\eta^{\beta\sigma}\partial_\mu T_{\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta}.$$
We want to find an expression of the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial T_{\alpha\beta}}-\partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu T_{\alpha\beta})}\right)=0, \quad \text{ for } \alpha,\beta=0,1,2,3,$$
in terms of our Lagrange density. Observe that, since $\mathcal{L}$ does not depend explicitly on $T_{\alpha\beta}$ (the dependance is on their derivatives), the first term is zero. On the other hand, 
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu T_{\alpha\beta})}=\frac{\partial }{\partial (\partial_\mu T_{\alpha\beta})}\left(\partial_\mu T_{\rho\sigma}\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta}\right)=\frac{\partial(\partial_\mu T_{\rho\sigma})}{\partial(\partial_\mu T_{\alpha\beta})}\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta}+\frac{\partial(\partial_\nu T_{\alpha\beta})}{\partial(\partial_\mu T_{\alpha\beta})}\partial_\mu T_{\rho\sigma}.$$
However, I do not know how to proceed from here because this index notation still confuses me. The result should be $2\partial^\mu T^{\alpha\beta}$ and, if I arrive to that point, I know how to conclude the problem.

Can anyone explain to me how these derivatives give the right answer? I insist that this is the first time I encounter the sum Einstein convention. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having said that this is not the way I would carry out a variation, you are almost there. Take $\partial_{\alpha}T_{\mu \nu}=T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}$, then 
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}}=\eta^{\rho \sigma}\eta^{\lambda \beta} \eta^{\tau \gamma} \frac{\partial }{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}} (T_{\lambda \tau,\rho}T_{\beta \gamma,\sigma})=\eta^{\rho \sigma}\eta^{\lambda \beta} \eta^{\tau \gamma} (\delta^{\mu}_{\lambda}\delta^{\nu}_{\tau}\delta^{\alpha}_{\rho}T_{\beta \gamma,\sigma}+\delta^{\mu}_{\beta}\delta^{\nu}_{\gamma}\delta^{\alpha}_{\sigma}T_{\lambda \tau,\rho})
$$
if you use that $\eta$ is symmetric in its indeces, you can change the index name of one term in the parenthesis so as to add it to the other and get
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}}=2\eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \gamma}\eta^{\alpha \sigma}T_{\beta \gamma,\sigma}
$$ 
then 
$$
0=\partial_{\alpha}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}}=2\eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \gamma}\eta^{\alpha \sigma}\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\sigma}T_{\beta \gamma}=2\eta^{\mu \beta}\eta^{\nu \gamma} \square (T_{\beta \gamma}).
$$
Let me remark a few things: first this derivation is completely general so that you can take any metric $g$ in place of $\eta$, second when you use indeces try not to repeat those in formulas when making substitution like you did in the calculation of $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}}$ since when you use Einstein convention (i.e. repeated indeces are summed over) then
$$ 
\frac{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}}{\partial T_{\mu \nu,\alpha}} = \sum_{\mu,\nu,\alpha =0}^3\delta^{\mu}_{\mu}\delta^{\nu}_{\nu}\delta^{\alpha}_{\alpha}=4\cdot 4\cdot 4=64.
$$
In general a good way to check the notational correctedness of your formula is to ensure that to each *free* index (i.e. not repeated index) in the left hand side there is the same free index in the right hand side.